# Go - Failing escape analysis on different slice headers with shared data

Tags: go, reflection, unsafe, escape-analysis

I'm working on a project where I frequently convert []int32 to []byte. I created a function intsToBytes to perform an inplace conversion to minimize copying. I noticed that Go's escape analysis doesn't realize that `ints` and `bytes` reference the same underlying data. As a result, `ints` is overwritten by the next function's stack data and `bytes` lives on and references the overwritten data.

The only solution I can think of involves copying the data into a new byte slice. Is there away to avoid copying the data?

```golang
func pack() []byte {
   ints := []int32{1,2,3,4,5} // This does not escape so it is allocated on the stack
   bytes := intsToBytes(ints) // 'ints' and 'bytes' are different slice headers
   return bytes 
   // After the return, the []int32{...} is deallocated and can be overwritten
   // by the next function's stack data
}

func intsToBytes(i []int32) []byte {
    const SizeOfInt32 = 4

    // Get the slice header
    header := *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&i))
    header.Len *= SizeOfInt32
    header.Cap *= SizeOfInt32

    // Convert slice header to an []byte
    data := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&header))

    /* Potentital Solution
    outData := make([]byte, len(data))
    copy(outData, data)
    return outData
    */

    return data
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you come to the conclusion that these do not escape, since the output which shows escape analysis also shows that the entire call is inlined and there is nothing to escape, hence modifying the result does not effect the next result. You're also going to get `vet` errors here from misusing the `reflect.SliceHeader`, and if you remove that `intsToBytes` is a single expression: https://play.golang.org/p/k1rwnZbZ4dS. Make a more complete [mre] showing what problem you are having.

Comment: While the example here doesn't appear to have a problem, the warning about misuse of the reflect headers is there to prevent subverting escape analysis with `unsafe`, so perhaps that is your entire issue.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your feedback! I was wondering how the inlining was going to affect the escaping. You are also correct about the go vet errors. I should have run that before I submitted the question. Since I was using `SliceHeader` incorreclty I started looking around to see how to fix it. This example performs the conversion and doesn't have the go vet errors. [https://play.golang.org/p/B7hIfIuHvDa](https://play.golang.org/p/B7hIfIuHvDa)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about the new Slice function, which is very convenient.